# How to solve the dispachertimer hang the application in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, dispatchertimer

am used the below code for automatically call for reporting.But after 30seconds the application hangs(i.e UI is freeze)for several seconds.

How to solve this without hanging problem.
below is my code

```
     System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer2 = new  
                                        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

  dispatcherTimer2.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer2_Tick);
     dispatcherTimer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
     dispatcherTimer2.Start();

    private void dispatcherTimer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     automaticreportfunction();

   }
```

After 30seconds it hangs the application,how to solve this

Comment: What do you do in the `automaticreportfunction`-method? I think that there a lot of work will be done

Comment: @Tomtom:yes that works fine,but problem is after 30seconds the applications freeze several minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DispatcherTimer` runs in a Background-Tread. All methods in the Tick-Event are running in the `UI-Tread`. That's why your application will freezer. You will have to move your `automaticreportfunction()` to a background-thread in order to keep your UI alive.

Therefor you have several opportunities. Personally I prefer the usage of a `BackgroundWorker` (I know that there a other ways, but I like this one most). So in your `Tick`-Event you can do something like:

```
private void dispatcherTimer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += (bs, be) => automaticreportfunction();
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (bs, be) => dispatcherTimer.Start();
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

I would also stop the timer when you enter the tick-method and restart it again after your `automaticreportfunction` finished because otherwise you could enter the method again while your execution still runs.

Comment: `backgroundWorker.DoWork += (bs, be) => automaticreportfunction();
` is the same as  `backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorkerOnDoWork;` where BackgroudnWorkerOnDoWork is a method like: `private void BackgroundWorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)    {
            automaticreportfunction();
        }`

Yes. It's an event-handler

Comment: ya good ,but now automaticreport doesnotcall based on backgroundwork

Comment: what do you mean with `doesnotcall`? your method will not be executed? Are you sure? Have you tried to debug it? What are you doing insid `automaticreportfunction()`?

Comment: :yes am debugged ,but the control does not goes to backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorkerOnDoWork; for automaticreportfunction()

Comment: What are you doing insid automaticreportfunction()? Do you create UI-Controls or something else in there?

Comment: :Inside automatic report am use this----- public void automaticreport2()
        {
           
            foreach (var autsdyid in LoadStudyIdentifiers())
            {
//code
}

private string[] LoadStudyIdentifiers()
        {
      
           
            //code
            return results.ToArray();
        }